# Load pyomo solution when optimizer returns an error

Tags: optimization, pyomo, ipopt

In optimization a pyomo model with ipopt, I am receiving the message:

> Restoration phase converged to a feasible point that is
>   unacceptable to the filter for the original problem.
>   Restoration phase in the restoration phase failed.

This means that ipopt found a feasible point, but because it was unacceptable to the filter, ipopt did not continue to try to find a local optima to the problem. This returns a status of "error" to pyomo, and I am not able to load the results. Attempting to use pprint on the instance gives me all of the variables at their starting point. I would like to find out the values of the variables when ipopt ran into the restoration failure. Is there a way I can do this?

Here is the code I'm using

```
try:
    results = opt.solve(instance, tee=tee)
    instance.solutions.load_from(results)
except Exception:
    print('MA.Solve encountered an error:', sys.exc_info()[0])
    traceback.print_exc()

    with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
        instance.pprint(ostream=f)
```

And here is the output

```
MA.Solve encountered an error: <class 'ValueError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "----", line 393, in ----
    results = opt.solve(self.instance, tee=tee)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py", line 657, in solve
    default_variable_value=self._default_variable_value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/PyomoModel.py", line 249, in load_from
    % str(results.solver.status))
ValueError: Cannot load a SolverResults object with bad status: error
```

Comment: I think you are trying to load solver results, but the solver cannot find a solution to your opt. problem. So it gives an error? Btw `opt.solve(instance, tee=True)`

Comment: @Icedkk: It has not found a locally optimal solution, I agree, but it has found a solution. This is information of interest to me. Also, tee is a variable in my script, and I am running with it set to True.

Comment: Hi @RichardShadrach did you find an answer for this? I have a solution in pyomo with a slight constraint violation and I'd like to load as well.

Comment: @user27886: If the solver ipopt gives infeasible, pyomo will load the solution. I'm not familiar with other solvers

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar question/use case. I am using Pyomo.DAE to integrate a PDE (square problem). My model is named `full`.

```
SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(full, tee=True)
```

IPOPT has a restoration failure on the final iteration.

```
 679r 0.0000000e+00 1.86e-09 4.04e+02 -11.0 1.27e-07  -6.0 1.00e+00 4.88e-04f 12
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
 680r 0.0000000e+00 9.31e-10 1.29e-12 -11.0 1.52e-08  -6.4 1.00e+00 1.00e+00s 36
Restoration phase converged to a point with small primal infeasibility.

Number of Iterations....: 680

                                   (scaled)                 (unscaled)
Objective...............:   0.0000000000000000e+00    0.0000000000000000e+00
Dual infeasibility......:   1.2866497665187040e-12    1.2866497665187040e-12
Constraint violation....:   3.4197000786662102e-10    9.3132257461547852e-10
Complementarity.........:   9.9004652442607800e-12    9.9004652442607800e-12
Overall NLP error.......:   3.4197000786662102e-10    9.3132257461547852e-10


Number of objective function evaluations             = 1800
Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 328
Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 1800
Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 719
Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 681
Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =    479.182
Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =     21.007

EXIT: Restoration Failed!
```

My model is probably horribly ill-conditioned; reformulation is in progress. Nevertheless, I would really like to examine the IPOPT solution after the final iteration. Pyomo throws this error immediately after the IPOPT output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-a1795f441929> in <module>
----> 1 SolverFactory('ipopt').solve(full, tee=True)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyomo/opt/base/solvers.py in solve(self, *args, **kwds)
    631                             result,
    632                             select=self._select_index,
--> 633                             default_variable_value=self._default_variable_value)
    634                         result._smap_id = None
    635                         result.solution.clear()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyomo/core/base/PyomoModel.py in load_from(self, results, allow_consistent_values_for_fixed_vars, comparison_tolerance_for_fixed_vars, ignore_invalid_labels, id, delete_symbol_map, clear, default_variable_value, select, ignore_fixed_vars)
    249                 raise ValueError("Cannot load a SolverResults object "
    250                                  "with bad status: %s"
--> 251                                  % str(results.solver.status))
    252         if clear:
    253             #

ValueError: Cannot load a SolverResults object with bad status: error
```

My understanding is that Pyomo is protecting me (the user) from myself and not giving me the solution after the restoration failure. Is there a way to override this?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem. I am having a similar problem in which I cannot load an infeasible solution (with a constraint violation).

Comment: Any easy hack in this example is to set the iteration limit to 599. Ipopt will then exit with a different status and you can examine the solution.